# Proper handling of maintained references in closures to avoid memory leaks

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, lambda, delegates

(Prefix: For those who see this and think TL;DR, actual question is at the end)

Since discovering lambdas and delegates in C#, I've become a big consumer of them. However, I have an ongoing concern when it comes to releasing memory on objects that are maintained in a closure, especially when dealing with nested closures. For example, consider the below from a set of classes I'm writing for what I'd consider to be "appropriate" `INotifyPropertyChanged` behaviour.

```
public static PropertyChangedEventHandler GetHandler<TDependant, TDependantHost, TFoundation, TFoundationHost>
    (
        this TDependantHost target,
        PropertyChangedEventHandler invokeTarget,
        Expression<Func<TDependantHost, TDependant>> dependantRef,
        Expression<Func<TFoundationHost, TFoundation>> foundationRef,
        Expression<Func<TDependantHost, TFoundationHost>> foundationHostRef
    )
    where TDependantHost : ISupportsDependencyManager
    where TFoundationHost : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string foundationName = GetPropertyInfo(foundationRef).Name;
    string dependantName = GetPropertyInfo(dependantRef).Name;
    string foundationHostName = GetPropertyInfo(foundationHostRef).Name;
    Func<TDependantHost, TFoundationHost> foundationHostRefCompiled = foundationHostRef.Compile();
    PropertyChangedEventHandler oOut = null;

    // Complex situation. This is more complex because whilst TDependantHost bears a relationship to TFoundationHost
    // the actual dependency is on a property in TFoundationHost.
    // oOut is the property changed handler that will be attached to target, so it needs to
    // - Raise changed events whenever foundationHostRef would evaluate to a different object
    // - Whenever that change occurs, attach a new PropertyChangedEventHandler to the new foundationHost
    // - ... which also handles removal of itself from target so as to guarantee
    oOut = (s, e) =>
    {
        var sender = s as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (sender == null)
            return;
        if (e.PropertyName == foundationHostName)
        {
            // The Foundation Host has changed. So we need to attach a new inner PropertyChangedEventHandler to it.
            PropertyChangedEventHandler innerHandler = null;
            innerHandler =
                (s2, e2) =>
                {
                    // Caller safety...
                    var innerSender = s2 as TFoundationHost;
                    if (innerSender == null)
                        return;

                    // Check and see if this eventhandler still points to the right object
                    // If it does, we'll keep going - otherwise, got to remove the event handler and return
                    if (foundationHostRefCompiled(target) != innerSender)
                    {
                        innerSender.PropertyChanged -= innerHandler;
                        return;
                    }

                    // Now we know that the inner handler is executing for an entity that still bears the correct 
                    // relationship to target. So we just check the same way as usual - did foundation just change?
                    // If so, so did dependant
                    if (e2.PropertyName == foundationName)
                        invokeTarget.SafeInvoke(target, dependantName);
                };

            // since the foundation has shifted, the dependency will also have changed
            // Raise a handler for it.
            invokeTarget.SafeInvoke(sender, dependantName);
        }
    };
    return oOut;
}
```

What this is supposed to do (and it might - still need to test though, and I think I need a couple of null checks here and there) is:

- When a reference type property on target changes, raise a `PropertyChanged` event for the dependant property (identified by `dependantRef`)
- In addition, attach a `PropertyChanged` handler to `foundationHost`, so that if foundation changes, target gets notified
- Ensure target doesn't get notified for `foundationHost`s that are no longer related to it by resolving `foundationHostRef` before execution of the event handler, and detaching if that happens.

So using the above logic, and leaving aside the question of `foundationHost`s that are nested more than one layer deep (this is a work in progress), it looks like any object that has EVER been referred to by `foundationHostRef` will maintain a closure reference to target even when it is no longer related to it, at least until it tries to raise an event.

Now my understanding of this is that the event handler I've created could easily stop the memory occupied by target from ever being released. All that would need to happen would be for some object to occupy `foundationHostRef` at some point, then get reassigned elsewhere, and have a longer lifetime than `target` Depending on what `target` is doing that could be anywhere from annoying (`target` is a singleton that doesn't take up much memory) to catastrophic (`target` gets created and nulled thousands of time over program lifetime, and has some property that occupies a lot of memory, and GC never collects it).

**So, my question:** What built in protection is there, if any, against this kind of thing? And if there isn't, how should I tweak my delegates/lambdas so that they stop being evil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can two two things to mitigate this risk:

1. If you think that a particular piece of code is at risk try not to use lambdas there. Do closures the old way: By creating an instance method on a class.
2. Install the [Resharper Allocation Plugin](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.HeapView/). It is quite educational to see all the allocations that common C# idioms make. The plugin tells you what variables were closed over. R# warns about variables that were captured "implicitly" as well (not sure what that means but it sounds like a useful warning for you).

> it looks like any object that has EVER been referred to by foundationHostRef will maintain a closure reference to target even when it is no longer related to it

I don't follow the code given above completely. There never is an unbounded amount of objects being referenced from a closure. The number of object references is constant.

What can be an issue, though, is that local variables that appear to be unused or out of scope can still effect a strong reference. This is because the C# compiler does not null out closure variables when they become unused. It does not do that for normal locals either but the JIT is smart enough to do an equivalent thing.

Explicitly nulling variables that you want cleared works in every case I know of (although it probably is not guaranteed by the C# spec).

Comment: ReSharper would probably help, but my trial license has expired, and for the time being, didn't find I was using it enough to justify buying a full license. Useful to know that unused local variables can still effect a strong reference, though. I was thinking about shifting parameters to `WeakReference`s for use inside lambdas, but it sounds like that doesn't go far enough. Still, if I null the parameters after generating `WeakReference`s, that might work, I'm thinking...

Comment: Note, that WeakReference introduces a semantic change. If no other references exist the WeakReference will eventually become null at a random point in time. It's usually a safer, saner approach to manage references right instead of using weak ones.

Comment: Very true - I've just got a feeling it's easier to reconstitute a weakreference and check consistency than it is to rely on strong references that I really don't want to kick around after Target should be released; and it sounds like the only way to do that is to null target and invokeTarget before the (extension) method finishes. I can probably therefore live with the semantic change most of the time, provided I check null and live status live status first.